# Input data into a webpage textbox

Tags: html, vba

I am trying to fill in a textbox on a webpage using VBA. the following is the code for the textbox:

```
<DIV id=win5divInputKeys_bind1>
  <INPUT tabIndex=11 id=InputKeys_bind1 class=PSEDITBOX style="WIDTH: 88px" maxLength=11 value=walter name=InputKeys_bind1>
</DIV>
```

I would like to change the value (currently `walter`) using VBA. I think it is part of a table but not sure. I can send the entire code via email if needed, as it is quite long.

I get to this page by clicking on a link in another webpage. This webpage then opens in a new window.

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: please re-read your question, and decide if you gave enough information. ...  and this time, pretend that we know nothing about you, and that we cannot see your computer

Comment: `IE.document.getElementById("InputKeys_bind1").Value = "Blah"` where `IE` represents an instance of Internet Explorer.  Plenty of answered questions here on SO with similar requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You could right mouse click (RMB) on the textbox you are trying to fill> Click inspect element and copy the piece of the html code that is selected/highlighted in Chrome or IE, (Or probably any other browser). (And removing/modifying all non-public variable names/locations/information).

And share that code in your question. (Just paste it in the text field where you ask your question, select it, and press the {} symbol above in the editing options, or manually indent every line with 4 spaces)

Based on the classes that are in that code you can write a vba module (from Excel, press Alt + F11, add new module, and add the following code:

```
 sub Populating_a_textbox
 '2. fill in something
        Set elements2a = ie.document.getElementById("classname_of_something")
        elements2a.Focus
        elements2a.Click
        'insertdata
        elements2a.innerText = "NotWalter"

end sub
```

When for example you can read a class = "classname_of_something" highlighted when you rmb>clicked the textbox, or think that that class it the class that needs to be filled.

In your case:

```
 sub Populating_a_textbox
     '2. fill in something
     Set elements = IE.document.getElementById("InputKeys_bind1")
     elements.Value = "Your text"
     'or
     elements.innertext = "Your text"
end sub
```

In the long run, it's more beneficial if you understand how and why it works the way it does. 
Others benefit from that knowledge as well. You could show effort to try and completely formulate your question as @jsotola suggested by for example sharing your isolated attempts so far.

Comment: Actually I think my question was formulated quite well. I made the suggestion of emailing my code as a way of reducing the question length. Also, when I get a solution to a question I always post it. And I will continue to go so. In the meantime, if you want to be an internet troll go find a social page.

Comment: Thank you, your comment made me re-read my answer and your question, I seemed very unfriendly even though my intention was good, I read the reason you asked for off the record email conversation wrong, so I adapted my answer.